# What it means when PM(K) of ps gets negative values?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I got the following negative PM (The amount of pageable memory that the process is using, in kilobytes) values when execute the `ps` command. What it means when the values are negative?

```
PS H:\> ps sqlservr

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   5947    4145 -1218888    1537304   981 ...50.77   8344 sqlservr


PS H:\> ps sqlservr

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   6060    4172 -1218876    1537316   981 ...52.08   8344 sqlservr


PS H:\> ps sqlservr

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   6481    4258 -1218832    1537376   981 ...56.55   8344 sqlservr
```

Answer (score 0):

The PM field is a 32bit number, and the value in it comes from a 32bit system call. The biggest number that can fit in a 32bit field is 4GB.

It appears that the paged memory that sqlservr is using is bigger than 4GB.

But that doesn't matter because it turns out that Process objects also contain 64bit properties. You can just use those instead. To get the paged memory, do this:

```
(ps sqlservr).PagedMemorySize64
```

To get the value in KB (like the "PM(K)" field is), do this:

```
(ps sqlservr).PagedMemorySize64 / 1kb
```